# How can I randomly distribute rows in one table to rows in another table in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to figure out a SQL query that will distribute records from one table to another table randomly.

for example :
I have a table of Customers, and I want to assign each a car out of a table of cars.

I want to make sure that the car are randomly distributed, but there is no property of an Customers that would predict which car they would receive.

**Customers:**
(Jon,Sam,Sara,Jack,Adam,Adrian)

**Cars:**
(BMW,Dodge,Lexus)

**Result:**

(Jon-BMW,Sam-Lexus,Sara-BMW,Jack-Dodge,Adam-Dodge,Adrian-BMW)

How can i do that in Oracle SQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with t as
  2    (select u.name ||'-'||a.name comb,
  3       row_number() over (partition by u.name order by dbms_random.value(1, n.cnt)) rn
  4     from customers u cross join cars a
  5     join (select count(*) cnt from cars) n on 1 = 1
  6    )
  7  select t.comb
  8  from t
  9  where rn = 1;

COMB
-----------------------------------------
Adam-Lexus
Adrian-BMW
Jack-Lexus
Jon-BMW
Sam-Dodge
Sara-Lexus

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One method that might be more efficient than a full cross join is:

```
select c.*, cc.car
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value(1, cc.cnt) as seqnum
      from customers c cross join
           (select count(*) as cnt from cars) cc
     ) c join
     (select cc.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from cars cc
     ) cc
     on cc.seqnum = c.seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

if no limit to use all cars and DB resources:

```
select customer_name||'-'||car_name result 
from (
    select u.name customer_name, c.name car_name, 
        row_number() over ( partition by u.name order by dbms_random.value ) ord
    from customers u
    cross join cars c
)
where ord = 1
```